# Pandas Split String in colum into colums with 0/1 ; get dummies on all characters of a string

Tags: python, pandas

Very likely this question was answered, but I can not find a good title. I have this pandas data structure, based on a given excel sheet:

| other columns | Code |
| --- | --- |
| ... | ABC |
| ... | CAB |
| ... | R |

I want to get this:

| other columns | A | B | C | R |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| ... | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| ... | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Of course, I could iterate over each row and so this manually, but all ideas in my head will either be slow or memory consuming or both.

What is the one line solution here?

Comment: df.loc[df['code'].str.contains('A'), 'A'] = 1 Repeat for each letter.

Comment: @Henry I don't think the duplicate really applies as there was no explicit separator here

Comment: @mozway My thought was that I would use that duplicate target if it were say a separator of `'_'` instead of a comma. I didn't think that no delimiter wad distinct enough. I think this is both a good sign post and it won't auto redirect since it has an upvoted and accepted answer. But it also will direct people to the more general case of any delimiter. You are welcome to reopen if you disagree. Just ping me so I can remove my comments.

Comment: @Henry keep it as you think is best, you also have a fair point. Doesn't really matter in fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) with an empty separator to get all letters:

```
df['Code'].str.get_dummies(sep='')
```

joining to original data:

```
df2 = df.drop('Code', axis=1).join(df['Code'].str.get_dummies(sep=''))
```

output:

```
  other columns   A  B  C  R
0           ...   1  1  1  0
1           ...   1  1  1  0
2           ...   0  0  0  1
```